# How can I bind data to the contents of a Run?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textblock

I want to construct a `TextBlock` consisting of several `Run` elements, with their contents bound to `string` variables, but Visual Studio complains, saying that one can only bind to a dependency property, which `Run.Text` isn't.

Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [BindableRun](http://fortes.com/2007/03/bindablerun/) class - that should probably do what you want.